# Conditional Formatting based on date and other cell with multiple options

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm having trouble with conditional formatting. I would like a cell with a date to be highlighted after a certain amount of time has passed. That amount of time depends upon another cell. For instance, A1 says "Monthly" and I want A2 to highlight after a month has passed. B1 says "Weekly" and I want B2 to highlight after a week has passed.

These work:

> =AND(TODAY() - $H7 > 7, $G7 = "Weekly")
>
> =AND(TODAY() - $H7 > 14, $G7 = "Bi-weekly")
>
> =AND(TODAY() - $H7 > 28, $G7 = "Monthly")
>
> =AND(TODAY() - $H7 > 56, $G7 = "Bi-monthly")

I basically want to be able to change G7 from "Weekly" to "Monthly" and it change H7 to the proper amount of time passed.

Thank you!

Comment: btw Welcome to [Web Applications](/tour "Web Apps Tour")! I see your account is unregistered. Consider [registering your account](/users/login "Login") to avoid accidentally losing access to your content by switching devices, browsers, or clearing your cookies. [Registering](/users/login "Login") is quick and you gain access to more site features. For more info see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Add your conditions together. If at least one matches the result will be a non-zero number that Sheets will interpret as TRUE.

#### HLOOKUP

```
=TODAY()-$H7 >  HLOOKUP($G7,
   {"Weekly","Bi-Weekly","Monthly", "Bi-Monthly"; 
     7, 14, 28, 56}, 2, 0))
```

#### SUMPRODUCT

```
=LET(days,TODAY()-$H7, max,$G7,
   SUMPRODUCT(
     (max="Weekly")*(days>7), 
     (max="Bi-Weekly")*(days>14), 
     (max="Monthly")*(days>28),
     (max="Bi-Monthly")*(days>56)))
```

#### AND

```
=LET(days,TODAY()-$H7, max,$G7,
   AND(max="Weekly", days>7)+ 
   AND(max="Bi-Weekly", days>14)+
   AND(max="Monthly", days>28)+
   AND(max="Bi-Monthly", days>56))
```